# How do I parse a <HTML> as a string in Google App Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I want to know if it is possible to parse a  string in Google App Script.

Here is my problem:

If I type the following code in Google App Script Editor:

```
function test() {

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://www.pudim.com.br/");
 Logger.log(response.getContentText());

}
```

I will get in the Log the Page´s HTML, as you can see:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/SiteBuilder/css/Pessoal03Palha.css" type="text/css" />
    <meta name="Keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="Description" content="" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="SiteBuilder_Principal">
        <div id="SiteBuilder_Topo" style="background-image: url('/SiteBuilder/UploadUsers/pudim.com.br/634607701572677834.png');">
            <div id="SiteBuilder_Topo_Objeto">

            </div>
            <div id="SiteBuilder_Topo_Frente"></div>
            <div id="SiteBuilder_Logo" style="top:54px; left:70px;;">
                <img src="/SiteBuilder/UploadUsers/pudim.com.br/634607755224560419.jpg" border="0" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="SiteBuilder_Menu">
            <div id="SiteBuilder_Menu_Area">
                <style>
      .dv_position{float:left; padding-right:12px; font-family: Arial; font-size: 10px; color: White; font-weight: bold;}
    </style><div class="dv_position"><table><tr valign="top"><td><img src="/SiteBuilder/Templates/Pessoal03/Pessoal03Palha/imagens/tc_contrutor_template03_pessoal_palha_icon.gif"></img></td><td><a href="index.html"></a></td></tr></table></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <table id="SiteBuilder_TbConteudo" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td align="left" valign="top">
                    <div id="SiteBuilder_Conteudo">
                        <div style="text-align: center;"><img alt="" src="/SiteBuilder/UploadUsers/pudim.com.br/pudim.jpg" style="border-width: 0px; border-style: solid;" /></div>

                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div id="SiteBuilder_Rodape">
            <div id="div_RodapeViewMode" class="div_RodapeViewMode">
                <a href="mailto:pudim@pudim.com.br">pudim@pudim.com.br</a>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="SiteBuilder_HostedBY" style="float: right; color: #333333">
            Hosted by <a href="http://www.tecla.com.br/" target="_blank" style="font-weight:bold; color:#333333">Tecla</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I´ve used a very simple site as a example. The variable "response" will be a string. And I want to be able to get from this string whatever value I want, for example the source of the imagine or the page tittle.

Ultimately I want to use Google SpreadSheet to get some information from a series of URL. I would have the URL in one column and in the other columns I would like to get the name an value of some products from an e-commerce.

I realize that there might be some easier ways to accomplish that. I´m asking for a Google App Script solution because this is the language that I´m most familiar with. However, if there is no possible way to accomplish that using Google App Script, I would be very glad to hear about some alternatives.

Thank You Very Much!

Answer (score 0):

You want regular expressions: w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp, could also be done with indexOf() but it's alot harder.

To get all the image src property:

```
var ind;
while( ind = /<img src="([^"]*)/.exec( response.getContentText()) ){ 
   Logger.log(ind[1])
}
```